# Alternative for ResxResourceWriter in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, resx, resource-files

I need to create Resources(resx-files) in my .NET Core based application. Until now I used to use ResxResourceWriter from System.Windows.Forms for that.
Any suggestions how to handle this task in .NET Core?

Beside our existing software, which has it's own localization approach based on some binary file, the new software should benefit from existing expensive translations and even have some translation synchronization of terms, when they added to the binary file.

Of course, you can use XmlSerialization. The question is, whether there is a formal way to create/manage Resx-files in .NET Core.

Comment: It is almost always a bug, the class was meant to implement your own Visual Studio designer.  Which you should never do with .NETCore.  Use normal XML serialization or make a minimal effort to describe why you think you need it.

Comment: I'm looking to do a similar thing where I want to have a custom `IStringLocalizer` that can automatically append to a `resx` file for translations. It would be sweet to be able to do it with a resource writer rather then custom xml serialisation.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: With WinForms open sourced, one could modify the original source to remove windows-specific dependencies https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/master/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Resources/ResXResourceReader.cs

Answer (score 10):

Tada! https://www.nuget.org/packages/ResXResourceReader.NetStandard

I extracted ResXReourceWriter and ResXResourceReader from the Winforms github and packaged them for .NetStandard

Answer (score 0):

I happen to have a [library](https://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/html/N_KGySoft_Resources.htm) with full .resx support. You can find the usual [`ResXResourceReader`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/html/T_KGySoft_Resources_ResXResourceReader.htm), [`ResXResourceWriter`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/html/T_KGySoft_Resources_ResXResourceWriter.htm) or [`ResXResourceSet`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/html/T_KGySoft_Resources_ResXResourceSet.htm) classes. I addressed a lot of security issues of the original WinForms version, while you can enforce full compatibility.

I introduced a lot of new features as well, for example, my `ResXResrouceSet` can be expanded, and there are several new types such as [`ResXResourceManager`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/html/T_KGySoft_Resources_ResXResourceManager.htm) that works as a regular `ResourceManager` but works directly on .resx files and it supports adding new resources during runtime.

I already [offered](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/54657#issuecomment-896372843) it for the .NET codebase so maybe it will be migrated at some time. Until then, it is available from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.CoreLibraries).